# Convert a string of numbers and letters into a string of numbers

Tags: python

I have a list where each element contains both numbers and letters and I just want the numbers out of them.

```
fp = 'filepath' (This is a text file btw)


with open(fp, "r") as file:

    lst = []
    si = len(lst) - 6 
    for line in file:
        lst.append(line) 

print(lst[si])
```

---

This outputs the following from my txt file:

```
sersic    : (   83.25,    78.32)  *33.90*     2.29    2.14    0.82    65.95
```

Python considers this entire thing to be a string but I want to turn it into a list and extract the numbers 2.29 and 2.14 from it. How would I go about doing this?

Eventually I would like a list along the line of:

```
final_lst= [2.29,2.14]
```

Comment: Explore regular expressions

Comment: Could you explain the rules why you want those two numbers? Why not `83.25` or `0.82`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the output of si like `si.split()` which will give you a list of numbers and then you can get all numbers you wants using list index.
So your code should be:

```
numbers = si.split()
```

This will give you output as `['(', '83.25,', '78.32)', '33.90', '2.29', '2.14', '0.82', '65.95']`

Now you can create a list as per your requirements as follows:

```
final_list = [numbers[4], numbers[5]]
```

Comment: You missed the calls to `float`.